# System no longer boots, gave up waiting for root file system device. Alert /dev/sda2 does not exist/ dropping to a shell

Tags: boot, 22.04

On the computer:

- Dell Inspiron n7110
- 8 GB RAM
- i7-2670QM
- with Windows7

I want to install Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Ubuntu only, on a new drive).
I bought a brand new 512 GB SSD.

I swapped with the previous one on which Windows 7 was running.

I tried to make using the Etcher app, a flash drive with Ubuntu installation. Unfortunately, it did not work and only with the help of the Rufus application I was able to fire up the Ubuntu installer.
After a successful installation (message from the installer), after restarting I received a message:

```
operating system not found
```

Using the same flash drive, each time I ran the Try it versions of Ubuntu (I assume that since it succeeded, everything is OK with the flash drive) and verified how the installer formats the drive and sets partitions. It comes out differently each time. I chose to format the entire drive by default (no additional advanced options )

I have updated the BIOS twice. The first time, from a07 to a13 - nothing was frowned upon. Only after installing the modded version, I can access to UEFI and Legacy related settings.
A BIOS update, led to the point where I am currently stuck:

```
System no longer boots, gave up waiting for root file system device.   
Alert /dev/sda2 does not exist/ dropping to a shell".
```

[image]

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  You say you installed multiple times. Did you always install in UEFI boot mode? You show ESP & /, but if you installed in old BIOS boot mode, you have BIOS version of grub in MBR and if UEFI set to boot in BIOS mode, that old grub would try to boot erased install.

Comment: When starting up the Dell computer,keep tapping F12 button to bring up UEFI/BIOS boot menu. Does the menu show the options for 'Windows' or 'Ubuntu'?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V4btG4bJBC/
I always chose the standard installation

@PaulBenson 
It is always the same menu, it only changed after installing the modded version providing additional UEFI/Legacy options.

Answer (score 0):

What helped in my case:

1. update of the modded BIOS, with access to UEFI settings
2. preparing the partition beforehand, because by default the installer did it differently every time.
3. proper installation from USB prepared in RUFUS. Usb prepared in etcher unfortunately did not work.